# Вывод суммы столбцов Angular

Tags: typescript, angular2, angular, table

Недавно начала работать с Angular. После выведения строки при помощи checkbox в футере должна динамически меняться сумма.

Не понимаю как прописать логику, чтобы при выборе одной или нескольких строк в подвале прописывалась сумма для конвертации.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему
Вот код:

````
<div class="modal" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="toggle" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="txt-20">Convert to DGTX</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="toggleModal()">
          <img src="assets/images/close.svg" alt="">
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- Position Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="currency">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Currency</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <input type="checkbox" class="d-flex" id="check" (click)="toggleSum()">
              <label for="check">{{element.currency}} </label></mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <!-- Name Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="main">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Main Balance </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.main | number: '1.2-5'}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <!-- Weight Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Value in DGTX</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value | number: '2.2-3'}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-inline">
        <div class="summ d-flex">
          <p>You Will Get:</p>
          <div class="value txt-14">{{summ}}<p>DGTX</p></div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Convert</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  main: number;
  currency: string;
  value: number;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {currency: 'DUSD', main: 9000, value: 173421.23},
  {currency: 'USDT', main: 2500, value: 43219.64},
  {currency: 'BTC', main: 0.23189, value: 28870.42},
];
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-convert',
  templateUrl: './modal-convert.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-convert.component.scss']
})
export class ModalConvertComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['currency', 'main', 'value'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  toggle = true;
  summ = 0;
  check = true;
  toggleModal() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  }
  toggleSum() {
    if (this.check === true) {
      this.summ = 1;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
````

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете описать проблему более внятно?

Comment: Не понимаю как прописать логику, чтобы при выборе одной или нескольких строк в подвале прописывалась сумма для конвертации

Answer (score 0):

Для получения индекса записи (строки) в таблице используйте:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i"> // или i = index
```

Для тега input в режиме checkbox используйте событие change:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="d-flex" id="check" (change)="toggleSum($event, i)">
```

Тогда в ts:

```
export class ModalConvertComponent implements OnInit {
    summ = 0;

    toggleSum(event, row) {
        if ( event.target.checked ) {
            this.summ += this.dataSource[row].value;
        } else {
            this.summ -= this.dataSource[row].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает!